# Jira Tempo : JSONP does not work?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am struggling with JSONP in Jira Tempo.

I just wanted to make their example work :

```
fn(
  {"values":
   [
     {
       "key":"",
       "value":"Please select..."
     },
     {
       "key":"0100",
       "value":"This is option ONE"
     },
     {
       "key":"0200",
       "value":"And here is option TWO"
     }
   ]
 }
)
```

Assuming I would have the script placed on my apache server http://www.example.com/foo.jsonp, what would be the URL I have to add to tempo?

Or does this simply not work with an Apache?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the cloud version of JIRA which is hosted on an SSL domain, you cannot use a Worklog Attributes service hosted on a non-SSL domain.

If you open the Chrome console when attempting to add a Tempo worklog, you will see the following error:

> [blocked] The page at 'https://XXX.atlassian.net/secure/TempoUserBoard!timesheet.jspa' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://XXX?callback=jQuery17203306205284316093_1425058485043&_=1425058490237': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Tempo uses JQuery on the client side to load the values dynamically. If you want to debug your service on a non-SSL server, run Chrome with the following key:

> chrome.exe **--allow-running-insecure-content**

Other potential problems:

- Tempo won't load the dynamic attributes until you select a specific issue in the time-booking dialog.
- You have to replace the **fn** in the example script dynamically based on the *callback* parameter. A static script won't work.

Comment: Hi, and thx for your comment. I am using Jira on my own system with a self signed ssl certificate. Does that make a difference? In the meantime I helped myself by adding checkboxes instead of a combobox selector.

Comment: @gorefest no, it shouldn't make a difference if you're running the Hosted version of JIRA.